# VRFv2Consumer contract request is always pending after requestRandomWords()

Tags: chainlink

I followed this [VRF v2 docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number/) to deploy the VRFv2Consumer contract on Rinkeby, and try to get random number, but my request always pending in **Subscription Manager** page after `requestRandomWords()`, However, the [transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4dacd35c93e53629808e118cae5ce60a9601f28aa0e9b8104d720a3ac663ad46) status is success

Why?

Comment: Hi, There has been some issues on Rinkeby lately that lead to slow VRF responses. Can you please try again and let me know if it still isn't responding in a timely manner (< 5 mins)? If it's still the case, I can reach out to the team

Comment: Thank you ! The problem is solved, the reason is that I sent too many requests to get number, but my LINK token of subscription is not enough